# Download Oracle Database 10g Release 10.1.0.2.0

Tags: database, oracle, download

where could I find such edition of Oracle? I need exact this and as I saw oracle.com doesn't support it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Does your organisation have a Support Contract?  If so you can probably get ahold of it from [MyOracleSupport](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html) (formerly Metalink).

If you have a license but no support then call your Account Manager.  They may be sympathetic, especially if they think there's future sales in prospect.

If neither case applies, then I'm not sure whether it would be ethical to help you find a copy.